# Nodejs Sequelize and passport Js, stuck on executing query when registing user

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

this is the problem I am having:

I have 3 models(users,favorites,cryptocoins)

```js
'use strict';
const { Model} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Cryptocoin extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Cryptocoin.init({
    coinId:{
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    coinName: DataTypes.STRING,
    coinPrice: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    coinAmount: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    totalValue: DataTypes.STRING,
    boughtOn: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Cryptocoin',
  });
  return Cryptocoin;
};
```

```js
'use strict';
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Favorite extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  }
  Favorite.init({
    favoriteId: {
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey:true,
        autoIncrement:true,
    },
    userId:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references:{
            model:'Users',
            key:'userId',
        },
        onDelete:'CASCADE',
    },
    coinId:{
        type:DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references:{
            model:'Cryptocoins',
            key:'coinId',
        },
        onDelete:'CASCADE',
    },
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Favorite',
  });
  return Favorite;
};
```

```js
'use strict';
const { Model} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
        
    }
  }
  User.init({
    userId: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
      },
    userName: DataTypes.STRING,
    passWord: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'User',
  });
  return User;
};
```

These all have migrations which work.

Now I have passport.js file which holds the passport stategies

```js
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

module.exports = function (passport, Auth) {

    const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy(
        
        {
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
            passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback

        }, function (req, username, password, done) {
            console.log("Signup for - ", username)
            const generateHash = function (password) {
                return bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8), null);
            }
            Auth.findOne({
                where: {
                    userName: username
                }
            }).then(function (user) {
                //console.log(user);
                if (user) {
                    return done(null, false, {
                        message: 'That username is already taken'
                    });
                } else {
                    const userPassword = generateHash(password);
                    const data = {
                        username: username,
                        password: userPassword,
                    };

                    Auth.create(data).then(function (newUser, created) {
                        if (!newUser)return done(null, false);
                        if (newUser) return done(null, newUser)
                    });
                    }
            });
        }
    ));
```

This file is called via `app.js` like so

just a snippet of the code in app.js

```js
const models = require('./models');

app.use(session({
    genid: (req) => {
        return uuid.v1();
    },
    name: 'Crypto-session',
    store:new fileStore(),
    secret: '------',
    resave:false,
    saveUninitialized:false,
}))
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport,models.User);
```

Now when going to my /register route and inputing a username and password this is what happens

```js
Signup for -  randomUser
Executing (default): SELECT `userId`, `userName`, `passWord`, `createdAt`, `updatedAt` FROM `Users` AS `User` WHERE `User`.`userName` = 'randomUser' LIMIT 1;
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`userId`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?);
```

And it's stuck at the executing (default) part, It gets uploaded to the database but without any username or password, console logging both of them shows they are being populated with values from my form.

Any idea how I can fix this issue ?

note: I am fairly new to express and nodeJs in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: After brainstorming and reading docs a bit these where the issues.

1. Ensure the deserializeUser function is either await or then based e.g

```js
    // deserialize user 
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        Auth.findByPk(id).then(function (user) {
            if (user) {
                done(null, user.get());
            } else {
                done(user.errors, null);
            }
        });
    });
```

2. Ensure you have a redirect in you route.post method e.g

```js
// route for register action
app.post('/register',passport.authenticate('local-signup',{ successRedirect: '/',
failureRedirect: '/register' }),function (req, res) {
});
```

3. Ensure all of your passport js fields match the database fields e.g

I had username and password, but in my database it is userName and passWord.

changing these like so

```js
const data = {
      userName: username,
      passWord: userPassword,
 };
```

Uploads everything to the database.